# Should the QA team be doing unit test?

Tags: testing

I come from a configuration management background using tools like chef. I have done quite a bit of code testing. Recently, I have been entrusted with the responsibility to work on the CI-CD of the various applications. But I am noticing a culture that’s quite not in line with my ideology.

Let’s say we have 4 environments in the CI-CD pipeline: `Dev, Test, Stage & Prod.` The `dev` environment is used by the developers to deploy and test the app before rolling out to the next stage (`test`). The `test` env is for the QA team to run their test. And `STAGE` is another env for 2nd layer of test by the QA folks before the code goes to `prod`.

Now, does it make sense for the QA or the `CI` process to run unit test while progressing/after deploying the code to (`TEST or STAGE`)? I agree that the `unit test` should be a part of the automated build. But unit test is mainly for the developers, for their code testing. The QA should be focus on the functional testing, load testing etc.. using their frameworks which may be selenium/protractor or LISA. Why should they be focusing on `junit` or `nunits`?

Comment: Is there any harm in running the unit tests? Do they take a lot of time?

Comment: There is no harm but i don't see any gain from re-running unit test on the same code while progressing to the next environment. I think the focus should be on the functional part to see if the application/website is actually working as it should be. Will there be a case, where the same code, will start failing unit test while deploying to another environment?

Comment: There can certainly be the case where not all of the correct code was deployed

Comment: Exactly and that will be caught by the functional test. Running unit test for all stage is just an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the developers do the unit testing.

Where I currently work, we follow TDD (Test Driven Development) so developers write the unit tests for their code first and then they write the actual implementation. This work goes on the Dev environment.

The QA people then do the acceptance tests and review stuff.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are short code fragments created by programmers or occasionally by white box testers during the development process. Unit tests are typically written and run by software developers to ensure that code meets its design and behaves as intended.

Hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is absolutely right. QA does not necessarily be doing Unit Testing (If that's what you mean). This testing is done by dev while they were writing the code (if they were in TDD environment or even if in BDD).

However if QA has used Junit to write their Selenium automated test cases then they will be using Junit to update and change their automated test cases.

It's little difficult to automate Selenium test cases using Junit whereas using other framework like TestNG is the best option to write automation test cases for Selenium.

I hope this answer your question.